# How replace top format mark after StreamWriter writing

Tags: c#, .net

I have a text stream data like :

```
<dimension>{{count}}</dimension>
<v>1</v>
<v>2</v>
<v>3</v>
....
<v>100000</v>
```

I use streamwriter to write data into a file (because I want to avoid OOM situation) and only after wrting all data then I colud know the `dimension` count.

So I'd like to replace `{{count}}` mark by the count after writing.

Steps logic like:

```
    var count = 0 ;
    using (var stream = File.Create(path))
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (var reader = GetReader())
    {
        while(reader.Read())
            count++;
            writer.Write(reader.GetValue());
        } 
        
        //Go to file top and edit/update/replace `{{count}}`
        stream.TopReplace("{{count}}",count);
    }
```

I've read :

- [string - C# Read text file line by line and edit specific line - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45958061/c-sharp-read-text-file-line-by-line-and-edit-specific-line)
- [c# - XmlReader - I need to edit an element and produce a new one - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502450/xmlreader-i-need-to-edit-an-element-and-produce-a-new-one)

so right now my way is read all data `into memory` then edit on it, but it loss streamwriter point...

Comment: You could write a 33 character (`<dimension>` + 10 digits (max length of an int value) + `</dimension>` comes to 33 characters) line at the start of the file. Once you've finished writing everything, seek back to the beginning and write (not writeline) your `<dimension>count</dimension>`. This would leave whitespace after the closing tag, but it's XML so it shouldn't matter (unless someone is parsing it by hand and not ignoring whitespace).

Comment: Failing that, you'll have to read the file line-by-line and write a new file.

Comment: *"only after wrting all data then I colud know the dimension count"* - you may want to make your implementation mockable to be able to simulate writing in first pass, obtain missing values and then do a real writing with all values known.

Comment: thanks @Llama I'm trying it now

Comment: @Sinatr yes, I want it.